# Character encoding error in idHTTP

Tags: php, delphi, utf-8, idhttp

I'm having a situation with TIdHTTP and TIdMultipartFormDataStream.

My code is:

```
  FormPHP := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  FormPHP.AddFile('imagem',AImagem,'image/jpeg');
  FormPHP.AddFormField('iduser',AIDUser,'text/plain');
  FormPHP.AddFormField('nome',ANome,'text/plain');
  FormPHP.AddFormField('data',AData,'text/plain');
  FormPHP.AddFormField('hora',AHora,'text/plain');
  FormPHP.AddFormField('mensagem',AMensagem,'text/plain');
  FormPHP.AddFormField('latitude','1','text/plain');
  FormPHP.AddFormField('longitude','1','text/plain');

  Response := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.ANSI);

  HTTP:= TIdHTTP.Create(self);
  HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
  HTTP.Request.Clear;
  HTTP.Request.ContentType:= 'multipart/form-data';  //application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  HTTP.Request.ContentEncoding:= 'MeMIME';
  HTTP.Request.CharSet:= 'utf-8';
  HTTP.Request.Referer:= 'http://observadordecascavel.blog.br/cadastro.php';
  HTTP.Post('http://observadordecascavel.blog.br/cadastro.php',FormPHP,Response);
```

This is the PHP script:

```
<?php 
    #cadastro.php - Cadastra os dados enviados na tabela online.
    $mysqli = new mysqli("mysqlhost","username","password","dbname");

    $iduser         = $_POST['iduser'];
    $nome           = $_POST['nome'];
    $data           = $_POST['data'];
    $hora           = $_POST['hora'];
    $mensagem       = $_POST['mensagem'];
    $latitude       = $_POST['latitude'];
    $longitude      = $_POST['longitude'];
    $imagem         = $_FILES["imagem"]['tmp_name'];
    $tamanho        = $_FILES['imagem']['size'];

    if ( $imagem != "none" )
    {
        $fp = fopen($imagem, "rb");
        $conteudo = fread($fp, $tamanho);
        $conteudo = addslashes($conteudo);
        fclose($fp);

        $queryInsercao = "INSERT INTO tabpainel (iduser, nome, data, hora, mensagem, latitude, longitude, imagem) VALUES ('$iduser', '$nome', '$data','$hora','$mensagem', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$conteudo')";

        mysqli_query($mysqli,$queryInsercao) or die("Algo deu errado ao inserir o registro. Tente novamente.");

        if(mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) > 0)
            print "Sucesso!";
        else
            print "Não foi possível inserir o registro";
    }
    else
        print "Não á foi possível carregar a imagem.";
  ?>
```

Explaining: My application post these fields to this PHP script and the php saves the data into a MySQL database and returns a response of "Sucesso!" to the application to inform the user that the data were saved. This text response is encoded in ANSI. I discovered that when i had to change the TStringStream encode to TEncoding.ANSI so it could recognize the "Não" word when something goes wrong.

Until the post, the variable *AMensagem* is ok, however, when the PHP receives the text, it's not correct. A text like this: "á Á é É" looks like this "=E1 =C1 =E9 =C9". This is saved in the mysql database.

I don't know if the problem is with the idHTTP or with TIdMultipartFormDataStream, or even with the PHP code. Everything works fine, it's just the encoding that i have no clue why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text that is transmitted to the server is not being encoded in UTF-8.

All of your `AddFormField()` calls are specifying the `text/plain` media type in the `ACharset` parameter instead of the `AContentType` parameter. Unlike `AddFile()`, the 3rd parameter of `AddFormField()` is the charset, and the 4th parameter is the media type.

```pascal
function AddFormField(const AFieldName, AFieldValue: string; const ACharset: string = ''; const AContentType: string = ''; const AFileName: string = ''): TIdFormDataField; overload;
```

By passing an invalid charset, `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` ends up using Indy's built-in raw 8bit encoding instead, which encodes Unicode characters `U+0000 - U+00FF` as bytes  `$00 - $FF`, respectively, and all other characters as byte `$3F` (`'?'`).  The text you are sending *happens* to fall in that first range.

`TIdFormDataField` does not currently inherit a charset from `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` or `TIdHTTP` (work on that is in-progress), so you have to specify it on a per-field basis.

On a side note, `MeMIME` is not a valid `ContentEncoding` value. And you should not be setting any `ContentEncoding` value for a `multipart/form-data` post anyway.

Try something more like this instead:

```pascal
FormPHP := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;

FormPHP.AddFile('imagem', AImagem, 'image/jpeg');
FormPHP.AddFormField('iduser', AIDUser, 'utf-8');
FormPHP.AddFormField('nome', ANome, 'utf-8');
FormPHP.AddFormField('data', AData, 'utf-8');
FormPHP.AddFormField('hora', AHora, 'utf-8');
FormPHP.AddFormField('mensagem', AMensagem, 'utf-8');
FormPHP.AddFormField('latitude', '1');
FormPHP.AddFormField('longitude', '1');

Response := TStringStream.Create('');

HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(Self);
HTTP.Request.Referer := 'http://observadordecascavel.blog.br/cadastro.php';
HTTP.Post('http://observadordecascavel.blog.br/cadastro.php', FormPHP, Response);
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
FormPHP := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;

FormPHP.AddFile('imagem', AImagem, 'image/jpeg');
FormPHP.AddFormField('iduser', AIDUser).Charset := 'utf-8';
FormPHP.AddFormField('nome', ANome).Charset := 'utf-8';
FormPHP.AddFormField('data', AData).Charset := 'utf-8';
FormPHP.AddFormField('hora', AHora).Charset := 'utf-8';
FormPHP.AddFormField('mensagem', AMensagem).Charset := 'utf-8';
FormPHP.AddFormField('latitude', '1');
FormPHP.AddFormField('longitude', '1');

Response := TStringStream.Create('');

HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(Self);
HTTP.Request.Referer := 'http://observadordecascavel.blog.br/cadastro.php';
HTTP.Post('http://observadordecascavel.blog.br/cadastro.php', FormPHP, Response);
```

Either way, the field text will be encoded using UTF-8 instead of Ansi.

---

**Update**: Now, with that said, `AddFormField()` sets the `TIdFormDataField.ContentTransfer` property to `quoted-printable` by default.  However, PHP's `$_POST` does not decode `quoted-printable` by default, you would have to call [`quoted_printable_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) manually:

```php
$iduser         = quoted_printable_decode($_POST['iduser']);
$nome           = quoted_printable_decode($_POST['nome']);
$data           = quoted_printable_decode($_POST['data']);
$hora           = quoted_printable_decode($_POST['hora']);
$mensagem       = quoted_printable_decode($_POST['mensagem']);
$latitude       = quoted_printable_decode($_POST['latitude']);
$longitude      = quoted_printable_decode($_POST['longitude']);
```

If you don't want `TIdFormDataField` to encode the UTF-8 text using `quoted-printable`, you can set the `ContentTransfer` property to `8bit` instead:

```pascal
FormPHP.AddFormField('iduser', AIDUser, 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
FormPHP.AddFormField('nome', ANome, 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
FormPHP.AddFormField('data', AData, 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
FormPHP.AddFormField('hora', AHora, 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
FormPHP.AddFormField('mensagem', AMensagem, 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
FormPHP.AddFormField('latitude', '1');
FormPHP.AddFormField('longitude', '1');
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
with FormPHP.AddFormField('iduser', AIDUser) do begin
  Charset := 'utf-8';
  ContentTransfer := '8bit';
end;
with FormPHP.AddFormField('nome', ANome) do begin
  Charset := 'utf-8';
  ContentTransfer := '8bit';
end;
with FormPHP.AddFormField('data', AData) do begin
  Charset := 'utf-8';
  ContentTransfer := '8bit';
end;
with FormPHP.AddFormField('hora', AHora) do begin
  Charset := 'utf-8';
  ContentTransfer := '8bit';
end;
with FormPHP.AddFormField('mensagem', AMensagem) do begin
  Charset := 'utf-8';
  ContentTransfer := '8bit';
end;
FormPHP.AddFormField('latitude', '1');
FormPHP.AddFormField('longitude', '1');
```

Either way, you can then use your original PHP code again:

```php
$iduser         = $_POST['iduser'];
$nome           = $_POST['nome'];
$data           = $_POST['data'];
$hora           = $_POST['hora'];
$mensagem       = $_POST['mensagem'];
$latitude       = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude      = $_POST['longitude'];
```

Whether you use `quoted-printable` or not, the PHP variables will end up holding UTF-8 encoded text.  If you need the variables to be in another encoding, you will have to convert them as needed, by using either:

1. [`utf8_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) (which decodes to ISO-8859-1):

   ```php
   $iduser         = utf8_decode($iduser);
   $nome           = utf8_decode($nome);
   $data           = utf8_decode($data);
   $hora           = utf8_decode($hora);
   $mensagem       = utf8_decode($mensagem);
   $latitude       = utf8_decode($latitude);
   $longitude      = utf8_decode($longitude);
   ```
2. [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

   ```php
   $iduser         = mb_convert_encoding($iduser, 'desired charset', 'utf-8');
   $nome           = mb_convert_encoding($nome), 'desired charset', 'utf-8');
   $data           = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'desired charset', 'utf-8');
   $hora           = mb_convert_encoding($hora, 'desired charset', 'utf-8');
   $mensagem       = mb_convert_encoding($mensagem, 'desired charset', 'utf-8');
   $latitude       = mb_convert_encoding($latitude, 'desired charset', 'utf-8');
   $longitude      = mb_convert_encoding($longitude, 'desired charset', 'utf-8');
   ```
3. [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

   ```php
   $iduser         = iconv('utf-8', 'desired charset', $iduser);
   $nome           = iconv('utf-8', 'desired charset', $nome);
   $data           = iconv('utf-8', 'desired charset', $data);
   $hora           = iconv('utf-8', 'desired charset', $hora);
   $mensagem       = iconv('utf-8', 'desired charset', $mensagem);
   $latitude       = iconv('utf-8', 'desired charset', $latitude);
   $longitude      = iconv('utf-8', 'desired charset', $longitude);
   ```

Finally, when sending a response back to the client, you need to encode text when it contains non-ASCII characters.  You should also be using [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to let the client know which charset is being used for that encoding:

```php
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK"); 
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"');

if ( $imagem != "none" )
{
    ...
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) > 0)
        print utf8_encode("Sucesso!");
    else
        print utf8_encode("Não foi possível inserir o registro");
}
else
    print utf8_encode("Não á foi possível carregar a imagem.");
```

Comment: Changes made but the problem is still there.

Comment: @wordermorr which versions of Delphi and Indy are you using?

Comment: Delphi Seattle and Indy 10.6.2.5298

Comment: I have tried somethings here and what i found out is that my server is returning the text response encoded in ANSI. Should i use 'ansi' in the charset?

Comment: @wordermorr: no, because `'ansi'` is not a valid charset name. See [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). What text response are you referring to now? Earlier, you said the posted text was being saved as-is in a DB without being decoded properly. Is a text response also being sent back to the client? Can you show the actual PHP script?

Comment: I've added the php script in the question and explained how it works.

Comment: Thank you Remy! Thank you for your time and patience. Problem solved!